# Remove item coincide in array "distinct"

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to remove item coincide in array and produce distinct array

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "Peter"},
  {"name": "Hana"},
  {"name": "Jone"},
  {"name": "Peter"},
  {"name": "Peter"},
];
```

Result:

```
var arr = [
  {"name": "Peter"},
  {"name": "Hana"},
  {"name": "Jone"},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```dart
arr = arr.asMap().map((i, m)=> MapEntry<String, Map>(m["name"], m)).values.toList()
```

Comment: Your welcome. Mark the answer as correct if this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = arr.toSet().toList()
```

check `toSet()` [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-collection/ListMixin/toSet.html)

Comment: I followed but result still does not change

Comment: could you try to print just 
` arr.toSet().toList() `

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class to parse the data, then you can compare the objects and filter your list.

**Your Person class**

```
    class Person {
      final String name;

      Person({this.name});

      factory Person.from(dynamic json) => Person(name: json["name"]);

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": name};

      @override
      bool operator ==(Object other) =>
          identical(this, other) || other is Person && name == other.name;

      String toString() => "name : $name";
    }
```

**Usage**

```
      var arr = [
        {"name": "Peter"},
        {"name": "Hana"},
        {"name": "Jone"},
        {"name": "Peter"},
        {"name": "Peter"},
      ];

      final objectList = arr.map((json) => Person.from(json)).toList();

      var filteredList = [];
      objectList.forEach(
        (item) {
          if (!(filteredList.contains(item))) {
            filteredList.add(item);
          }
        },
      );

      print(filteredList);
```

Comment: you can mark the answer as solved if it helps you :)

Comment: If you override `==`, you must also override `hashCode`, or Sets won't work.  Any two objects that are "equal" must also have the same hashcode.  The inverse is not necessarily true.  See https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html.